# Epson Printer Not Printing

Tags: windows, printer, epson-stylus

Forgive me if this question is not in the correct StackExchange. 
I have a Epson Stylus NX400 on a 64 bit Windows Vista which can copy things, scan them, communicate it's ink levels to the computer and send jobs to the queue, but when I try to print it gives me a really basic (uninformative) error "Print Preview Error" and "Error Printing." I have tried updating the drivers on the website, uninstalling and reinstalling the whole printer, unplugging/plugging it in, new ink, nozzle checks but I can't seem to get it to print from any program or web browser. I've googled but mostly I'm finding uninformative manuals and as I have been on a Mac for work for several years I cannot think of any other methods of printer troubleshooting.

Any further actions recommended?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has since been resolved by:

```
Uninstalled ALL printers (network printers included)
Unplugged the device
Stopped the Spooler service and deleted anything in the spool
Deleted USB Host controllers
Rebooted the PC (Host Controllers were automatically created once again)
Installed the printer driver
Followed prompts and finished installation
```